# What is the difference between subquery and a joined subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

**What is the difference between these two mysql queries**

```
select t.id,
(select count(c.id) from comment c where c.topic_id = t.id) as comments_count
from topic;
```

**AND**

```
select t.id,comments.count from topic
left join
(
   select count(c.id) count,c.topic_id from comment c group by topic_id
) as comments on t.id = comments.topic_id
```

I know theres not much information. Just wanted to know when to use a subquery and joined subquery and whats the difference between them.

Thanks

Comment: Your second example is a join to a derived table. The benefit is the derived table is generated once, set based. The first correlated subquery risks being executed once per row of the `topic` table

Comment: So you mean subquery is ok for retrieving a single record ? and second one for retreving list ?

Comment: @reverbnation if you want to aks a question from StuartLC, You should call him by `@`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, but I would also add a third option (the more standard way of doing this):

```
select t.id, count(c.topic_id) as count
from topic left join
     comment c 
     on t.id = c.topic_id
group by t.id;
```

The first way is often the most efficient in MySQL.  MySQL can take advantage of an index on `comment(topic_id)` to generate the count.  This may be true in other databases as well, but it is particularly noticeable in MySQL which does not use indexes for `group by` in practice.

The second query does the aggregation and then a join.  The subquery is materialized, adding additional overhead, and then the `join` cannot use an index on `comment`.  It could possibly use an index on `topic`, but the `left join` may make that option less likely.  (You would need to check the execution plan in your environment.)

The third option would be equivalent to the first in many databases, but not in MySQL.  It does the join to `comment` (taking advantage of an index on `comment(topic_id)`, if available).  However, it then incurs the overhead of a file sort for the final aggregation.

Reluctantly, I must admit that the first choice is often the best in terms of performance in MySQL, particularly if the right indexes are available.  Without indexes, any of the three might be the best choice.  For instance, without indexes, the second is the best if `comments` is empty or has very few topics.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a bit vague. Which one is better for without indexes ? and which one for indexes ?